# Blight mechanics (items and roles)

Tags: werewolv.es

How do the Blight mechanics of the Demonlord role and the Gaunt of Blight item interact? Do they share the same pool of Blight or do they work separately?

Comment: Hi Shabas, welcome to Arqade. Self-answering questions is certainly encouraged here, however you will want to phrase the question in such a way that actually asks a question, and not like a forum post. I anticipate this thread could be reopened if you rephrased it to just ask a question without any backstory or fluff.

Comment: @Gigazelle thanks for the welcome and your feedback! I've worded my question a little bit differently now. There was some fluff with a comical inside reference and all that, which I understand made the post vague and ambiguous. I've removed it both in my question and answer.

Comment: A question still has to be a question, I'm afraid.  Try to focus less on the motivations of why you're asking, and more on the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Frank thanks for your input, I've edited the text and now focused on the actual question that I was asking.

Answer (score 1):

Item Blight (Gauntlet of Blight) is separate from Demon-role Blight.
If there are multiple Gauntlets, their effects are all bundled in the same pool of Blight.

Also: Demon roles are not unique, so multiple Demonlords could Blight simultaneously into the same Blight pool